# "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" when creating array of struct using an range in Swift 5

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to create an array of a simple struct using a range. What's the proper way to do it?

```
struct Stock {
   var id = UUID()
   var name: String = ["MSFT", "AAPL", "TSLA", "GOOG", "AMZN", "FB"].randomElement()!
}
//Generates the error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"
var companies = (1...100).map { Stock() }
```

I'm on Swift 5.2 and Xcode 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `_ in`  as you don't use `$0` inside the block

```
var companies = (1...100).map { _ in Stock() }
```